# How to handle Oracle Error [ Unique Constraint ] error

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table named TABLE_1 which has 3 columns

```
row_id      row_name    row_descr
1           check1      checks here
2           check2      checks there
```

These rows are created through a front end application. Now suppose I delete the entry with row_name check2 from the front end and create another entry from front end with row_name check3, in database my entries will be as follows.

```
row_id      row_name    row_descr
1           check1      checks here
3           check3      checks
```

Now row_id if you observe is not a normal one time increment, Now my problem is i'm writing an insert statement to automate something and i don't know what i should insert in the row_id column. Previously i thought it is just new row_id = old row_id +1. But this is not the case here. Please help

EDIT : 
Currently im inserting like this which is Wrong :

```
insert into TABLE1 (row_id, row_name, row_descr
) values ( (select max (row_id) + 1 from TABLE1),'check1','checks here');
```

row_id is not a normal one time increment.

Comment: yes it is a normal one time increment. this is how it works when you autoincreament the `ids`. if you delete data it will not erase row_id. it still remain allocated unless you fire truncate command

Comment: So is there any way i can capture the row_id since it is not a normal increment?

Comment: How is the `row_id` column incremented? Using a `sequence` or some user defined logic?

Comment: Can i check it somehow? Currently im not sure. In mycase i was planning to increment it by 1 but then realised that is not the proper way

Comment: How are the values inserted? See the insert statement.

Comment: you can write your insert statement like this`insert into test_subhankar(s_col1,s_col2) select max(s_col1)+1,'abc' from test_subhankar`

Comment: Lalit i have pasted in EDIT Section

Comment: Now really your word is confusing us please let us know the incremental logic of the id column U are saying i don't know then how could you expect some one to help you.

Comment: Skip the max(row_id)+1 , use a sequence.

Comment: @Sathya, even a sequence can't guarantee that, strictly speaking!

Comment: @lalit well, if you're getting unique contraint errors with sequence, then either your relations are not setup properly or your application is doing a really bad job.

Comment: Ah! You are talking about the error mentioned by OP. I am saying generally, even a sequence cannot guarantee that it won't have gaps. Anyway, having said that, in this case a `sequence` is much better option. I would answer about `IDENTITY COLUMNS`.

Comment: Never ever use `select max() + 1` to generate unique values. It either results in wrong values (most likely) or will perform poorly for more than a single user.

Answer (score 2):

Never ever calculate ids by max(id)+1 unless you can absolutly exclude simultaneous actions ( which is almost never ever the case). In oracle  (pre version 12 see Kumars answer) create a sequence once and insert the values from that sequences afterwards.

```
create sequence my_sequence;
```

Either by a trigger which means you don't have to care about the ids during the insert at all:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER myTrigger
BEFORE INSERT ON TABLE1 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT my_sequence.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.row_id FROM DUAL;
END;
/
```

Or directly with the insert

```
insert into TABLE1 (row_id, row_name, row_descr
) values ( my_sequence.nextval,'check1','checks here');
```

Besides using `row_id` as column name in oracle might be a little confusing, because of the pseudocolumn `rowid` which has a special meaning.

To anwser your quetstion though: If you really need to catch oracle errors as excpetions you can do this with `PRAGMA EXCEPTION INIT` by using a procedure for your inserts. It might look somehow like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myInsert( [...] )
IS

   value_allready_exists    EXCEPTION;

   PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT ( value_allready_exists, -00001 );
   --ORA-00001: unique constraint  violated

BEGIN

 /* 
  *  Do your Insert here
  */ 


  EXCEPTION
    WHEN value_allready_exists THEN 
        /*
         * Do what you think is necessary on your ORA-00001 here
         */
END myInsert;
```

Answer (score 1):

`Oracle 12c` introduced `IDENTITY` columns. Precisely, `Release 12.1`. It is very handy with situations where you need to have a `sequence` for your primary key column.

For example,

```
SQL> DROP TABLE identity_tab PURGE;

Table dropped.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE identity_tab (
  2    ID          NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  3    text        VARCHAR2(10)
  4  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO identity_tab (text) VALUES ('Text');

1 row created.

SQL> DELETE FROM identity_tab WHERE ID = 1;

1 row deleted.

SQL> INSERT INTO identity_tab (text) VALUES ('Text');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO identity_tab (text) VALUES ('Text');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO identity_tab (text) VALUES ('Text');

1 row created.

SQL> DELETE FROM identity_tab WHERE ID = 2;

1 row deleted.

SQL> SELECT * FROM identity_tab;

        ID TEXT
---------- ----------
         3 Text
         4 Text

SQL>
```

Now let's see what's under the hood -

```
SQL> SELECT table_name,
  2         column_name,
  3         generation_type,
  4         identity_options
  5  FROM   all_tab_identity_cols
  6  WHERE  owner = 'LALIT'
  7  /

TABLE_NAME           COLUMN_NAME     GENERATION IDENTITY_OPTIONS
-------------------- --------------- ---------- --------------------------------------------------
IDENTITY_TAB         ID              ALWAYS     START WITH: 1, INCREMENT BY: 1, MAX_VALUE: 9999999
                                                999999999999999999999, MIN_VALUE: 1, CYCLE_FLAG: N
                                                , CACHE_SIZE: 20, ORDER_FLAG: N


SQL>
```

So, there you go. A `sequence` implicitly created by Oracle.

And don't forget, you can get rid off the `sequence` only with the `purge` option with table `drop`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not worried about which values are causing the error, then you could handle it by including a `/*+ hint */` in the insert statement.

Here is an example where we would be selecting from another table, or perhaps an inner query, and inserting the results into a table called `TABLE_NAME` which has a unique constraint on a column called `IDX_COL_NAME`.

```
INSERT /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(TABLE_NAME(IDX_COL_NAME)) */ 
INTO TABLE_NAME(
    INDEX_COL_NAME
  , col_1
  , col_2
  , col_3
  , ...
  , col_n)
SELECT 
    INDEX_COL_NAME
  , col_1
  , col_2
  , col_3
  , ...
  , col_n);
```

Oracle will blow past the redundant row.  This is not a great solution if you care about know WHICH row is causing the issue, or anything else.  But if you don't care about that and are fine just keeping the first value that was inserted, then this should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an exception build in which will raise whenever there will be duplication on unique key

```sql
DECLARE
emp_count number;
BEGIN
select count(*) into emp_count from emp;
if emp_count < 1 then
    insert into emp 
    values(1, 'First', 'CLERK', '7839', SYSDATE, 1200, null, 30);
    dbms_output.put_line('Clerk added');
else
    dbms_output.put_line('No data added');
end if; 
EXCEPTION
    when dup_val_on_index then
    dbms_output.put_line('Tried to add row with duplicated index');
END;
```